# Using PHP requires with varying directory levels

Tags: php, reference, directory, structure, require-once

I have a project with the following directory structure (simplified):

```
+css
+js
+partials
  -header.php
  -footer.php
+blog
  -index.php
-index.php
```

I want to `require_once` the `header.php` and `footer.php` in both the **blog** `index.php` and the **root** `index.php` using the following the code:

`<?php require_once("partials/header.php"); ?>`

But of course in the **blog** it doesn't work because the `header.php` points to the `css` and `js` files relevant to the **root** `index.php` not the blog `index.php`.

Is there away to negate this or do I need **two** `partials` folders one at the **root** level and one at the **blog** level.

Comment: I suggest to use absolute urls for css and js, instead of relative ones

Comment: i agree, but if you plan to reuse your scripts, constants really make life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a file called constants.php and include this at the top of your scripts. define this constant as your base path to the root directory of your files:

```
define("BASE_PATH", "http://www.yourURL.com/");
```

then to make sure the correct path is used simply prepend this constant to your urls:

```
require_once(BASE_PATH."/any_subdirectory/anyfilename.php");
```